# SqlConnection - how many failed pings to error?

Tags: .net, sql-server, networking, sqlconnection

OK, we have started to see quite a few SqlExceptions coming through on our network with the error 'A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. Physical connection is not usable'

This isn't stale connections, and in some of the places we are seeing this we are checking the connection.Open setting immediately before the line which throws the error.

Feedback from our network team states that 'missing a few pings here and there isn’t even considered a bad thing – it’s just something that happens from time to time'

What I'd like to know is, how much redundancy is built into the SqlConnection class? Will one failed packet or ping be enough to throw the exception. If not, how much re-trying is happening?

Obviously if we have to add our own retry logic around every bit of SQL code in our applications it could take months of effort, so I want to prove that it is more than 'missing a few pings here and there'!

Comment: I may not be a network guru but *"'missing a few pings here and there isn’t even considered a bad thing – it’s just something that happens from time to time'"* is network engineer BS. The stability of the network needs to be addressed instead of them brushing it under the carpet. It's likely dropping packets which is a bad thing. It's obviously bad enough to be affecting the SQL Server connectivity so should be addressed.

Comment: I'm heading somewhere in that direction - I will need to prove first that there is at least *some* redundancy in the .net Sql classes first though or we'll get accused of being the brittle party!

Comment: Chris, it's basic networking 101. How redundant do you expect the .Net SQL class to be? Is it suppose to fill in the gaps when packets are dropped? The issue here is network resilience and needs to be addressed, I'm not sure how they could possibly accuse you of being *"the brittle party"*.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't first try pinging a server before it connects it just attempts to negotiate over TCP/UDP *(whatever protocol you are using)* but fundamentally over IP. If it is failing in this layer then it is a network issue that should be addressed by whoever maintains the network.

Comment: `the connection.Open setting` cannot be reliable because TCP has no way to reliably tell whether a connection is broken or not. I assume you mean the `Status` property. That is totally stale.